# How convert this SQL query to Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT time,targetuser, count(targetuser),ipaddress FROM `test_index` WHERE `event_id`=4444 AND `status`=`0x10`  GROUP BY ipaddress,targetuser ORDER BY TIME DESC;
```

How convert this SQL query to Elasticsearch query?
is it possible?

Comment: We would like to see what you have tried and where have you stuck?

Comment: As your question is not clear, I am assuming you need some online plugins to convert your SQL queries. So, here is the link https://www.overvyu.com/sqltoelasticsearch